# Sacar por cada división el empleado con más beneficio (SQL)

Tags: sql, transact-sql

ahora sigo con el quebradero de cabeza...

Tengo estas dos tablas todavía:

Departamento

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ventas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El caso es, necesito  sacar por cada división, el empleado que más gana, suma de salario+comisión.

Estoy atascado aquí, ya que logro sacar el empleado que más gana pero solo de Galicia.

```
select top 1 SUM(p.salario+p.comision) as SalarioTotal, D.DIVISION
from DPTO D
INNER JOIN PERSONAL P ON P.DPTO = D.NUMDPTO
group by P.ID, D.DIVISION
order by SalarioTotal desc
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: quita `top 1` y en su lugar intenta con  `as SalarioTotal, DISTINCT D.DIVISION`

Comment: me da el mismo resultado... gracias

Answer (score 1):

Creo que estabas cerca. Primero de todo advertir que hay datos de comisión en `null`, y la suma de un número más null es null, por lo que hay que tratarlo.

Por otro lado con el `group by` es suficiente

```
select  D.DIVISION, SUM(p.salario + ISNULL(p.comision, 0) as SalarioTotal
from DPTO D
INNER JOIN PERSONAL P ON P.DPTO = D.NUMDPTO
group by P.ID, D.DIVISION
order by SalarioTotal desc
```

Comment: me da error por la funcion ISNNULL, de todas formas, acabo de lograr que me saque el resultado, pero uso un top 4...

Comment: Cierto, es ISNULL, con solo una "N"

Answer (score 0):

He conseguido sacar el resultado pero con top4, no filtrando por cada división, qué empleado gana más...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
select top 4 P.ID, D.DIVISION, SUM(p.salario+p.comision) as SalarioTotal
from DPTO D
INNER JOIN PERSONAL P ON P.DPTO = D.NUMDPTO
group by D.DIVISION, P.ID
order by SalarioTotal desc
```